# Parent proxy as https

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, https, proxy-server

On my computer, I have a direct connection to the internet,
But, I also have a different connection on my computer which is a https proxy running on a certain port.

On windows, I can access that proxy using proxifier & now I need a way to use that same proxy in linux.

Till now, I have already tried directly setting mozilla firefox ssl proxy and http proxy but no success. I also tried setting https_proxy but that also didnt help.

More info about proxy:

```
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $ telnet 1.2.3.4 8080
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to 1.2.3.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
connect google.com:80 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
```

EDIT: I basically want to know how to use **http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt proxy**. Also, pls see the https part of this page **http://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/proxy.htm**

Now, I need help as I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/), configure it,

```
[proxy]
client  = yes
accept  = 127.0.0.1:<localport>
connect = <proxyserver>:<port>
```

then set `http_proxy` to `http://127.0.0.1:<localport>` (where *localport* can be any unused port in the 1024..65535 range).

This way, your programs will see a plain HTTP proxy while stunnel will handle the SSL layer.

- client program ↔ stunnel [←Internet→] proxy server

Comment: btw, I tried that configuration and tried to use it as http proxy, it says "The connection was reset". Also, pls have a look at  http://sprunge.us/HEEc